# Activity starting another activity. Guarantee that the first activity's onPause will be called before second's onResume

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an Activity A and Activity B. Activity A starts Activity B.

Is there a guarantee that A's onPause() will always be called before calling B's onResume()?

This is related to this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862048/976367)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29):

> When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will
>   be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so
>   be sure to not do anything lengthy here.

Answer (score 2):

**onPause ()**

When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A. **B will not be created until A's `onPause()` returns**, so be sure to not do anything lengthy here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()

Comment: Yes, B will not be "created" (Does this created means onCreate?), but what will happened if B is already created? for example, B is in stop status?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `Activity A`'s `onPause()` will be called before passing to `Activity B`'s `onResume()` if the navigation is not the first time. If navigating to `Activity B` is for the first time, then `Activity B`'s `onCreate()` will be called after Activity A's `onPause()`. Take a look at **[Activity's Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/Activity.html)** for clear understanding.